# Rails 5: How Do I Correct Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a Rails 5 application in Heroku that does a login/logout using a sessions controller based on logic in Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I have done similar logic for several years starting with Rails 3. My application worked in localhost, production status using Passenger on my server and on Heroku. The same code is being executed. A couple of days ago I started getting the following errors when I try to log into the production version of my application on my server. However I'm still able to log into my application in localhost/development and on Heroku.

```
I, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.242323 #65501]  INFO -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c] Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-22 20:15:50 -0500
I, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.243524 #65501]  INFO -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c] Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.243945 #65501]  INFO -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RsEqEfiDw82E2YI17SVkkUcxhiqtUw75nC1i9GJmIYZlwjg6o0mXiHehCHP627iTOjyQoPA+mrmi+Bh99BxICQ==", "session"=>{"email_user"=>"pamela", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
W, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.245161 #65501]  WARN -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c] Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
I, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.246050 #65501]  INFO -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.248110 #65501] FATAL -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c]   
F, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.248546 #65501] FATAL -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
F, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.248894 #65501] FATAL -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c]   
F, [2017-04-22T20:15:50.249263 #65501] FATAL -- : [40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c] actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:195:in `handle_unverified_request'
[40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c] actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:223:in `handle_unverified_request'
[40a379f9-27c2-4923-a9ce-f310f96dbc4c] actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:218:in `verify_authenticity_token'
```

**application_controller**

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
include SessionsHelper
```

Log from localhost on the same machine where I'm able to successfully log in:

```
Started POST "/sessions" for ::1 at 2017-04-22 22:26:23 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zhkoMofyRdPcwQ7v2GOYltlRv2PJM8duzbuxJsa5dAy0je/yj1CRedQM/H1Zku2ukQbbG7YF6OZd4ootV0qolA==", "session"=>{"email_user"=>"myuserid", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "remember_me"=>"1", "commit"=>"Login"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (74.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "myuserid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["username", "myuserid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (22.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "users" SET "remember_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3[0m  [["remember_token", "75f5152d815e24e6ce7709cc93f34265ad9161be"], ["updated_at", 2017-04-23 03:26:23 UTC], ["id", 3]]
  [1m[35m (26.4ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 229ms (ActiveRecord: 124.5ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-04-22 22:26:23 -0500
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (7.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["remember_token", "75f5152d815e24e6ce7709cc93f34265ad9161be"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_meta_data.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_systemmessage.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 270ms (Views: 236.8ms | ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)
```

I have search solutions and just about all of them say to shut this off which I don't want to do especially considering that this is a database maintenance application. The only difference I can see between the three executions of the code is the value for remember_token in my table since each version is using a different database. I tried setting the remember_token field on the database to null but I still get the error. I have changed nothing related to the login/logout process so I'm really puzzled. I will clone what I have in Heroku and try again.

This is the first time I have seen this error in almost six years of Rails software development. I realize that I could very well have an attack but I don't know how to debug this error. The same code works in Heroku and localhost.

UPDATE: I looked at the page source of the production application on my server. This is what the header looked like before I attempted to log in and got the error. With my localhost version and the Heroku version the two statements like those below appear after login.

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="JoPFlDzY0SYSpOSq0dXgafSICgZ9qXJz/x4tX31owZPh3cu7fNR553iGPn5c+RnZVOuxiEolnoOin0Rkoay4Ag==" />
```

UPDATE: Attempt at overriding the class InvalidAuthenticityToken raised on line 195 in `rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb`. Currently this class has no statements. Huge guess at this point since I don't see any instructions for this or if this is even possible.

```
require 'action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection'

class XxxLogger < ActionPack::ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection
  source_root File.join(File.dirname(ActionPack::ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection.instance_method(:handle_unverified_request).source_location.first), "templates")

  class InvalidAuthenticityToken < ActionControllerError #:nodoc:
    logger.warn "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  end

end
```

Comment: According to your rails log, you also can't login at localhost. It's a CSRF problem, have nothing to do with the `remember_token`.

Comment: The log was from the program getting the error. I am logging in successfully at localhost on the same machine. This is why I'm at a complete loss. How can I only have a csrf problem in production and not localhost on the same machine? How do I debug a csrf error without turning off the forgery without exception?

Comment: if the log is from your production machine, why the ip is 127.0.0.1, you fake a post request by curl? In your own production website, if u can login, then you might encounter attack. If you can't login, then it's a logic bug. I think you should add more log to the production site, to show the http header, check if it  has key `X-CSRF-Token`.

Comment: I have a 'production' version of the application on my server that points to a different domain. The log I posted is from the production version of my application on my server where I get the error. I just added the log statements from when I successfully logged into my application in localhost. So the login in localhost on my application works but the login on my production application on my server does not. I have my log level set to :debug right now. I will figure out how to get more detailed logs in my rails app that hopefully include CSRF-Token and post my results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 tokens need to be verify, `form token`, `csrf token`. Any one of the tokens fail, will throw a `InvalidAuthenticityToken` exception.

At the production deploy directory, run `bundle show rails`, to find the exact `rails` directory, then add log to the related rails code, find detailed reason.

Add log in this way, `logger.warn "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity."`, it's the way how rails output log.

In `actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb` file, find why `any_authenticity_token_valid?` fail first.

And check this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24257#issuecomment-212203983, change to `users_path`, not `users_url`.

And take care of this,

`For Rails 5, note that protect_from_forgery is no longer prepended to the before_action chain, so if you have set authenticate_user before protect_from_forgery, your request will result in "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity." To resolve this, either change the order in which you call them, or use protect_from_forgery prepend: true.`

Comment: I need help on how to add the log for that and where. Thanks so much for your help. I just did a search but did not find any instructions for this.

Comment: just find the directory of the code that you deploy to, then run `bundle show rails`, find it's `rails` directory, then add code to rails related file `actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb`, this is where the exception throw. log can be add like `              logger.warn "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.`, just monitor how rails do it.

Comment: I don't have direct access to the Rails files because I use Ruby Version Manager (RVM) to install Ruby and Rails. I have created custom generators for migrations and models in lib/generators. I wonder if I can do something similar for overriding class InvalidAuthenticityToken (raised in line 195). If this is possible I need to know what to name my file and where to put it so logger can find it. I have updated my question with my attempt to create such a file.

Comment: I tried different things but they did not work. I decided to start over and clone the Heroku version of the application. I no longer get the error. Not sure what happened to cause the CSRF error but at least I had the Heroku version I can use as my new starting point on my server. Thanks so much for your help @seaify!

Comment: I spoke too soon. After a few minutes I got the error again. It looks like I may have to turn off CSRF or other drastic measures to get this fixed unless somehow I can override class InvalidAuthenticityToken and see what's causing the problem. I will ask that as a separate question.Thanks again @seaify!

Comment: No, you can direct access to the rails files. No matter that if you are using rvm or rbenv. If you are use `rvm`, then create a file called `.ruby-version`, which content is like `ruby-2.2.1`, it auto choose ruby version for you, when you `cd` to the directory. Because i also have never encounter this situation, so add log to the rails code is most reasonable way, no need to try to override the class.No matter what happen, at least we can go deep into the code.